# Failure to upload files to S3 from production environment

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, file-upload, aws-amplify, production

I have created a mobile application to upload images to the S3. I used [1][2] as a reference which makes use of AWS Amplify and React Native Expo to upload to the S3 Bucket.

In my local environment, the image is uploaded without any problem to the bucket I define, but when I put it in the test environment on Google Play, the image is simply not uploaded. I've set my bucket to public and it has permissions:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "xxxxxxx",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::folder/public/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I had configured my bucket for us-east-1 N.Virginia, but my app is addressed to Brazil on Google Play, could this be the problem?

It's confusing for me, because the application is working when I test it locally with EXPO.

[1] - https://github.com/eldorcodes/aws-image-upload

[2] - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2tSVBr80khk&list=LL&index=5